# What do I do with the neck?

Tags: meat

Often when I buy a dressed fowl, it comes with the neck, a bony object, which in the case of a duck, is suggestive of the male anatomy. This item is so hard and bony, it would take a heavy cleaver to cut it. What am supposed to do with this part of the duck?

Answer (score 8):

Use the neck to make a pan sauce...or add it to other poultry parts when you make stock.

Answer (score 5):

The neck from different fowl makes *very* flavourful broth! Most supermarkets used to carry packages of chicken necks that I'd buy for making soup. Sadly, few people use it now so stores no longer carry it. If you dry roast your fowl, the neck will end up dry and hard. But if you cover your roasting pan throughout most of the cooking time, some liquid will accumulate in the pan. Laying the neck on the bottom of the pan will make the neck meat tender and add a rich flavour to the juices.

I find the meat from chicken necks too much trouble to remove from its bones but turkey or goose neck has enough meat to make it worthwhile. I honestly consider it the best tasting part.